# sed + without cat command

Tags: shell, sed

the following syntax target is to add "_name4" on the first string in line that match the "name1 + name2 + name3" and to replace old word with new

```
cat  file | sed  '/name1 + name2 + name3/s/[^ ]*\>/&_name4/'  | sed s'/old/new/g' > new_file
```

my question : is it possible to do the same without using cat command?

Comment: Yes. sed happily accepts a filename as a command line argument. You can also chain sed commands with -e : sed -e '...' -e '...' -e '...' filename

Comment: The argument `-i` overwrite the current file and create a backup in the same folder. Not showing a screen output.

Comment: sed -i -e "command" -e "another commnand" file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You rarely need cat. You could do it like this:

```
sed '/name1 + name2 + name3/s/[^ ]*\>/&_name4/' file | sed 's/old/new/g' > new_file
```

You can also combine the sed commands:

```
sed '/name1 + name2 + name3/s/[^ ]*\>/&_name4/;s/old/new/g' file > new_file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed file -e <expr>` or `sed <expr> file`